# How to specify a COMSTR for the Command Builder in 'scons'

Tags: python, scons

Many of the builtin builders in scons have $*COMSTR variables which are used to change the default output of their associated Builder.  We can use $*COMSTR variables to optionally make our build processes more legible.

I would like to set a $*COMSTR variable for a Command builder.

```
target = 'mydb.db3'

populatesql = 'populate.sql'
sources = [populatesql]

command = '@sqlite3 $TARGET < ' + populatesql

built_database = env.Command(target, sources, command)
```

I've found that I can prefix my command with the '@' character to suppress output, but I've been unable to discover how to utilize a $*COMSTR with the Command builder.  Am I missing a trick here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't associate a command string with a builder. Command strings are associate with an Action object.

If you want a command string, just write something like this:

```
built_database = env.Command(target, sources, 
                             Action('mySqlite3', 'Generating $TARGET with sqlite3'))
```

or if you want that more fine tuned

```
env['SQLITE3COMSTR'] = 'Generating $TARGET from $SOURCES with sqlite3'
...
built_database = env.Command(target, sources, Action('mySqlite3', '$SQLITE3COMSTR'))
```

Comment: In your example code, what is the string 'mySqlite3' and how can I map it to the shell command?

Comment: use whatever shell command you want. `@sqlite3 $TARGET < $SOURCE` in your case, probably

Comment: Thank you Tom, this is exactly what I needed.  Much appreciation!

Comment: `SCons.Action.Action` is the full name. Likewise for ObjBuilders, pass the action object to `add_action(ext, action)` instead of just a str.